# Django Template Tag to get specific form field

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a survey application that creates forms of dynamic size.  I use the formula "question_id_part" where question is fixed, id is the id of the question being asked, and part is one of three parts.

In my template, I need to be able to group these by a category, so I loop through the categories in the survey, get all the questions in that category, then I have a template tag to get my form field.

```
{% load my_tags %}
...
{% for category in survey.category_set.all %}
    <h3>{{category}}</h3>
    {% for question in category.factor_set.all %}
        {% get_field_for_question_part question.id form "type" %} 
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
...
```

Then I have a corresponding template tag that looks like this:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_field_for_question_part(question_id, form, part):
    field_name = "question_%s_%s" % (question_id, part)
    field = form.fields[field_name]
    return BoundField(form, field, field_name)
```

My question is this:
By explicitly importing BoundField my template tag knows too much about how forms work internally and thus is brittle to future changes in the non-public behavior of forms.  Thus, it seems to me that the BoundField should be accessible somehow as a method on field -- but for the life of me I can't figure out what that method would be.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Slightly confused, are you creating fields on the fly or simply trying to access an existing field on the form?

Comment: simply trying to access existing fields.

Comment: Good question, I struggled with it for quite sometime until I landed here. In the template, we can simple do `form.field_name` but its not the same if we pass the same `form` object to a template tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_field_for_question_part(question_id, form, part):
    field_name = "question_%s_%s" % (question_id, part)
    return form.__getitem__(field_name)
```

See method definition on line 101 here: [django/forms/forms.py](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.2.4/django/forms/forms.py)

Comment: that should work, I can't imagine the form library ever factoring out __getitem__.  Thanks.

Comment: great answer. Struggled with it for sometime until I landed here. thanks!